# Setting geom_path color based on geom_point colors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot that looks like this :
[image]

This was generated using below code :

```
    longData<-structure(list(Var1 = c(6L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 5L, 1L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 1L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L), 
Var2 = 1:105,     value = c(6.41613198900092, 2.84458852788571, 3.9878654949938,     2.84458852788571, 3.9878654949938, 2.84458852788571, 3.9878654949938,     2.84458852788571, 3.9878654949938, 2.84458852788571, 3.9878654949938,     2.84458852788571, 3.9878654949938, 2.84458852788571, 3.9878654949938,     2.84458852788571, 3.9878654949938, 2.84458852788571, 3.9878654949938,     2.84458852788571, 3.9878654949938, 2.84458852788571, 3.9878654949938,     2.84458852788571, 3.9878654949938, 2.84458852788571, 3.9878654949938,     3.67686146649183, 5.00283179158014, 3.67686146649183, 5.00283179158014,     3.67686146649183, 2.74160383824537, 3.67686146649183, 2.74160383824537,     3.67686146649183, 3.99931926480599, 3.67686146649183, 3.99931926480599,     3.67686146649183, 3.99931926480599, 3.67686146649183, 4.35362802335279,     3.67686146649183, 4.35362802335279, 3.67686146649183, 4.35362802335279,     3.67686146649183, 4.35362802335279, 3.99724328049621, 4.57754674528668,     4.35362802335279, 3.67686146649183, 4.00444938820912, 3.79529789699833,     4.00444938820912, 3.79529789699833, 4.00444938820912, 3.79529789699833,     4.00444938820912, 3.79529789699833, 4.00444938820912, 3.79529789699833,     4.00444938820912, 3.79529789699833, 4.00444938820912, 3.79529789699833,     3.81138375279554, 3.79529789699833, 3.81138375279554, 3.79529789699833,     6.47487593052109, 3.79529789699833, 6.47487593052109, 3.79529789699833,     5.20602718404916, 3.79529789699833, 5.20602718404916, 4.57754674528668,     5.20602718404916, 3.98269499936379, 4.87403303366088, 3.98269499936379,     4.87403303366088, 3.98269499936379, 4.87403303366088, 3.98269499936379,     4.87403303366088, 3.98269499936379, 4.87403303366088, 3.98269499936379,     4.87403303366088, 3.98269499936379, 4.36554132712456, 3.65333094050839,     4.36554132712456, 3.65333094050839, 4.36554132712456, 3.65333094050839,     4.36554132712456, 3.65333094050839, 4.36554132712456, 3.65333094050839,     4.36554132712456, 3.65333094050839)), 
row.names = c(6L, 16L, 34L, 40L, 58L, 64L, 82L, 88L, 106L, 112L, 130L, 136L, 154L, 160L, 178L, 184L, 202L, 208L, 226L, 232L, 250L, 256L, 274L, 280L, 298L, 304L, 322L, 328L, 346L, 352L, 370L, 376L, 394L, 400L, 418L, 424L, 442L, 448L, 466L, 472L, 490L, 496L, 514L, 520L, 538L, 544L, 562L, 568L, 586L, 593L, 601L, 622L, 628L, 646L, 652L, 670L, 676L, 694L, 700L, 718L, 724L, 742L, 748L, 766L, 772L, 790L, 796L, 814L, 820L, 838L, 844L, 862L, 868L, 886L, 892L, 910L, 916L, 934L, 937L, 958L, 964L, 982L, 988L, 1006L, 1012L, 1030L, 1036L, 1054L, 1060L, 1078L, 1084L, 1102L, 1108L, 1126L, 1132L, 1150L, 1156L, 1174L, 1180L, 1198L, 1204L, 1222L, 1228L, 1246L, 1252L), class = "data.frame")
    longData$value <-round(longData$value)
    myPalette <- colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(11, "Spectral")))  
    sc <- scale_fill_gradientn(colours = myPalette(7))   

    ggplot(data=longData,aes(x=Var2,y=Var1)) + 
    geom_path(linetype = "dashed") + geom_point(shape=21, size = 7, aes(fill = value)) + 
    sc+ scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(1:12),labels=c("Path1-49","Path2-49","Path3-49","CorrPath-49","Path5-49","UnkownPath-49","Path1-51","Path2-51","Path3-51","CorrPath-51","Path5-51","UnkownPath-51"))
```

Now I want to color the dashed lines like this :

```
if(color of current geom_point == color of next geom_point)
   set the line color to the color of geom_point
 else 
   set the line color to black
```

How can I do this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, can you share a better sample of your actual `longData` df?  The one posted cannot make the graph you show based on the code given.  Also, please share your data frame as the output of `dput(longData)` so that it can be imported from the pasted text.  Finally, if you find your dataset is too big, either create an example dataset or use `sample()` to take a representative sample of your dataset.  For example, you can share 50 observations randomly selected from the datastet via:`dput(longData[sample(1:nrow(longData), 50),]`.

Comment: Hi, I have added the output of dput(longData), all the rows with NA values are removed, now longData has only those rows that are actually there in the plot. Is this fine ?

Comment: Yes thanks!  The only problem is that the `labs()` call doesn't work for your plot due to not having `rat`, `neuron`, etc in there.  Without that last line it works fine.

Comment: Okay now I'm noticing something: your if statement in the data posted is never true.  As you look through the 105 rows of `longData$Var2` (x axis), you never have two consecutive points that had the same value of `longData$value` (which would be the same color).  Am I getting that correct?

Comment: Yes, I think are correct. Can we give same color to the values that are in a particular range  ? longData$value can be split into 5 ranges and then assigned 5 colors according to the range ?

Comment: Yes, that's more appropriate anyway.  Either way, the answer will have to involve making `longData$value` (or the part used to compare the dots) a discrete variable, not continuous.  This is because evaluating equivalency breaks down for floating point numbers.  As an example, when you input this into the console, you get `TRUE` (although it's technically false:  `1.0000000000000001==1.00000000000000001`.

Comment: I have this added line to the code: `longData$value <-round(longData$value)` . Now there are no  floating point numbers in longData$value.

Comment: Yes, that's a start and exactly how I would suggest you "bin" your data easily.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213849/discussion-between-jumov-and-chemdork123).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an imperfect, yet workable solution.  Thank you for sharing your dataset, yet as I pointed out in the comments, it did not have any points that would satisfy your criteria indicated in the original question.  With that being said, I'll answer the question using a made up dataset similar to your own:

```
set.seed(54321)
df <- data.frame(
  x=1:50,
  y=sample(c('Path1', 'Path2', 'Path3'), 50, replace=TRUE),
  value=as.character(sample(1:5, 50, replace=TRUE))
)
```

#### The Question

As you posed, you wanted a way of drawing a line through all your data.  Points are colored according to a value, and the logic behind the color of the line is as follows:

- When two points adjacent to one another on the x axis have the same value (same color), the line color should match the value fill color *(here I'll make it a solid line)*
- when two points adjacent to one another on the x axis have different values (different colors), the line color should be black *(or here, it will be dotted and gray)*

For our purposes, `df$x` will be the x axis and `df$y` will be the y axis.  I made `df$y` discrete to match the OP's case.  ***Critically:*** I have also made `df$value` discrete.  Since the OP is intending to use this to compare two points based on the logic above, it's important to force the comparison among discrete values or "binned" values rather than comparing two continuous values.  This is due to unexpected results when comparing two doubles.  As an example, `1.0000000000000001==1.00000000000000001` evaluates to be `TRUE` in the console, even though it should be `FALSE`, whereas both of those numbers would lie within a "bin" that was `0.999 to 1.001`.

Simple plot below.  Goal is to change that dotted line according to above:

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + theme_bw() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = rainbow(5)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = rainbow(5))

g + geom_path(group=1, color='gray50', linetype=2) +
  geom_point(shape=21, size=4, aes(fill=value))
```

[image]

#### The Logic and Function

At first I thought we could just set the `color=value` to control color and `group=1` to control connectivity and we'd be all set... but that doesn't quite work properly:

```
g + geom_path(group=1, aes(color=value)) +
  geom_point(shape=21, size=4, aes(fill=value))
```

[image]

The problem lies in that the color is *always changing* according to `df$value`, where we want it to be black or gray when `df$value` changes, and then be drawn again when `df$value` is constant.  In essence, ***color-changing*** was not the problem, it was ***connectivity***.  In this case, I wrote `connect_check()` and used it to create another column in the dataset to control connectivity.

```
connect_check <- function(x) {
  return_vector <- vector(length=length(x), mode='double')

  grp_num <- 1
  previous <- x[1]

  for (i in 1:length(x)) {  
      if (x[i]==previous) {
        return_vector[i] <- grp_num
      }
      else {
        grp_num <- grp_num + 1
        return_vector[i] <- grp_num
      }  
    previous <- x[i]
  }
  return(return_vector)
}

# make a new column in the dataset
df$connected <- connect_check(df$value)
```

The result of `connect_check()` is a vector that increments the value *every time the value of that position in the vector changes*.  Here's a simple example:

```
> test <- c(1,2,2,4,7,5,5,5,2,2,3,8)
> test
 [1] 1 2 2 4 7 5 5 5 2 2 3 8
> connect_check(test)
 [1] 1 2 2 3 4 5 5 5 6 6 7 8
```

#### The Final Plot

The final solution here is to use the newly-created `df$connected` to control connectivity via the `group=` aesthetic, and assign `color=value` as before.  The only problem is that `ggplot` doesn't connect a line between a group of one point, so the kind of wonky workaround is that I'm using a `geom_path` call before to draw a light gray dotted line through *all* the points... then *overplotting* the points based on `df$connectivity` connection and their `df$value`.  In the end, it works.  I think there might be a way if you use `duplicated(df$value)`, but again... this works too.  :)

```
g +
  geom_path(linetype=2, color='gray50', group=1) +
  geom_line(aes(color=value, group=connected), size=1) +
  geom_point(shape=21, size=3, aes(fill=value))
```

[image]

*Note: I made the `size=` of the points smaller in the last plot so you can see the horizontal lines drawn where y remains constant and value either stays the same or changes.*

Final point: in your own dataset, like I referenced, you could "bin" the data.  I would go about that by making a separate column that assigns `longData$value_bin` first (which could just be as simple as `longData$value_bin <- round(longData$value, 1)`).  You would then use `df$value_bin` to compare the values of points to decide connectivity and color.  If point `fill=` is still set to `value`, but line `color=` is set to `value_bin`, you may not have precisely the same color.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation !! that worked really well.